# Plot only shows a line when connecting 1,000 points of a circle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a code that calculates a certain amount of points on the circumference of a circle, and when it runs with matplotlib, it only displays a line.

Here is the current code:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


h = float(input("Enter H value (center-x): "))
k = float(input("Enter K value (center-y): "))
r = float(input("Enter your R value (radius): "))
point_count = float(input("How many points do you want: "))

x_min = float(h - r)
x_max = float(h + r)

CENTER_POINT = (h, k)
CENTER_X = CENTER_POINT[0]
CENTER_Y = CENTER_POINT[1]

# Side 1
side = int(point_count / 2 + 1)
for i in range(0, side):
    r_count = 1
    increment_segment = float(r * r_count / side)
    r_count += 1
    x_min += increment_segment
    if x_min >= x_max:
        x_min -= increment_segment
        pass

    y_formula_positive = math.sqrt(math.pow(r, 2) - math.pow(x_min - h, 2)) + k
    y_formula_negative = 0 - math.sqrt(math.pow(r, 2) - math.pow(x_min - h, 2)) + k

    print(x_min, y_formula_positive)
    print(x_min, y_formula_negative)
    
    x_coor = []
    y_coor = []

    x_coor.append(x_min)
    x_coor.append(x_min)
    y_coor.append(y_formula_positive)
    y_coor.append(y_formula_negative)

    print(i)

plt.plot(x_coor, y_coor)
plt.show()
```

I believe that the calculations for the points are correct, and that the problem is with plotting it with matplotlib.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried plotting points with `plt.scatter`?

Comment: Since we are initializing the list in the loop process, please keep it outside the loop. `x_coor=[];y_coor=[]`

Comment: There are several issues with your calculations. you can start by observing the points in `x_coor` and `y_coor`. You overwrite them with an empty array in every loop iteration, and every time you calculate basically the same point. 

Also, I don't know if it's just a personal thing, or if this is actually part of the PEP-8, but I would avoid importing a module inside a loop. I think it's bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just noticed that I am setting it as a new array ever time in the for loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code with a bit of trigonometry:

```py
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


h = float(input("Enter H value (center-x): "))
k = float(input("Enter K value (center-y): "))
r = float(input("Enter your R value (radius): "))
point_count = int(input("How many points do you want: "))

points_x = []
points_y = []

for i in range(point_count):
    angle = 2 * math.pi * i / point_count
    points_x.append(h + r * math.cos(angle))
    points_y.append(k + r * math.sin(angle))

plt.scatter(points_x, points_y) 
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but there are math concepts that I don't understand yet.

Comment: Okay, the most important point is to initialize the point lists before the loop starts, as already pointed out in the comments above.