# Using turtle graphics to draw an n-pointed star

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to create a program in Python that will draw n-pointed star. I am having problems with stars that have 6, 14, 22, ... points. I cannot figure out how to solve for that pattern.

Here is what I have so far:

```
from turtle import *

# Settings 
speed(5)
width(1)
color('red', 'yellow') # outline, fill

x=int(input('Enter the number of points you want the star to have.')) 

begin_fill()

# If a star has even number of points, then it needs to be drawn differently 
if x%4 == 0:
    for i in range(x):
        y=180-360/x
        right(y)
        forward(300)
        y+=360/x

# For special cases such as 10, 18, 26, ...
elif x%2 == 0:
    for i in range(x):
        y=90+180/x
        right(y)
        forward(300)

# For special cases such as 6, 14, 22, ... 
# I need help here (this condition needs to be changed)...
elif x%2 == 0:
    for i in range(x):
        y=2*180/x
        right(y)
        forward(300)

# For stars with odd number of points
else:
    for i in range(x):
        right(180-180/x)
        forward(300)

end_fill()

hideturtle()

exitonclick()
```

Comment: So you want to check even numbers that are not multiples of 4?

Comment: Yes, but actually a subset of those numbers. For example, 10,18, 26, ... are also not multiples of 4 but I have found a way to draw stars in that pattern group. However, I cannot seem to do it for stars that have 6, 14, 22, ... points. Also, is there a more elegant way to solve this?

Comment: first draw on paper and calculate angles manually - and later use these informations in code to calculate angles.

Comment: you have `elif x%2 == 0` two times. Only first one will be executed.

Comment: I think you can't draw these stars using your method - you draw it using single line/polygon but star 6 is created by two separated triangles/polygons. Using single line/polygon You should draw only external line without internal elements.

Comment: [Related](https://xkcd.com/1029/).

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is only condition then maybe you should use lists/tuples

```
elif x in (10, 18, 26):

elif x in (6, 14, 22):
```

but this doesn't check all possible values

So you will need more complex comparition but I don't see any pattern to recognize `10,18,26` or `6,14,22` - all of them are divided by `2` so using `x % 2` is useless.

**EDIT:**

I see patterns

For list `6,14,22` I see

```
 6 + 8 = 14
14 + 8 = 22
```

or in other way

```
 6 = 6 + (8*0)
14 = 6 + (8*1)
22 = 6 + (8*2)
```

and this gives `if (x-6) % 8 == 0: ...` or simpler `if x % 8 == 6: ...`

For list `10,18,26` I see

```
10 + 8 = 18
18 + 8 = 26
```

or in other way

```
10 = 10 + (8*0)
18 = 10 + (8*1)
26 = 10 + (8*2)
```

and this gives `if (x-10) % 8 == 0: ...` or simpler `if x % 8 == 10: ...`

---

You draw stars using one polygon (one `for`-loop) but star 6 is created by two separated triangles (two polygons) so it need different method to draw.

[image]

But if you want to draw using only one `for`-loop then you should draw only external line (border) - and then you don't have to check `x % 2`.

This code draw star for any value

```
from turtle import *

# Settings 
speed(5)
width(1)
color('red', 'yellow') # outline, fill

#x = int(input('Enter the number of points you want the star to have.')) 
x = 6

begin_fill()

angle = (360/x)

print(x, angle)

for _ in range(x):
    forward(50)
    left(angle)  
    forward(50)
    right(2*angle)  # double angle

end_fill()

hideturtle()

exitonclick()
```

`star 6`

[image]

`star 14`

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Code which use `for`-loop to draw from 14 to 5

```
from turtle import *

# Settings 
speed(5)
width(1)
color('red', 'yellow') # outline, fill

#x = int(input('Enter the number of points you want the star to have.')) 
for x in range(14, 4, -1):

    begin_fill()
    
    angle = (360/x)
    
    print(x, angle)
    
    for _ in range(x):
        forward(50)
        left(angle)  
        forward(50)
        right(2*angle)  # double angle
    
    end_fill()
    
hideturtle()

exitonclick()
```

Result:

[image]

It shows that stars have differnt sizes so code would have to calculate different values for `forward()` but at this moment I skip this problem. First I would have to calculate it on paper.

---

**EDIT:**

Code which I used to draw `star 6` using two `triangles` (`red` and `green`)

```
from turtle import *

# --- functions ---

def triangle(width, outline):
    color(outline)

    for _ in range(3):
        forward(width)
        right(180-60)  

# --- main ---

width(2)

w = 150

triangle(w, 'red')

up()
forward(w//2)
left(90)
forward( (w//3 * (3**0.5)) / 2 )  # triangle: h = (a * sqrt(3)) / 2
right(90+(360/6))
down()

triangle(w, 'green')

hideturtle()
exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a very detailed answer. To address your first remark: I know that I needed a different way to differentiate both of those patterns as they are both even (divisible by 2) and that is why I wrote a comment above the second elif statement saying that code below is incorrect and needs changes (a different method). Thank you for the code though! I also knew that I could draw it only using the outline or with two different polygons but I was persistent to try and find the solution that could draw them in a same way as the others. I guess that is not a possibility.

Comment: do you have more values for list `6,14,22`? I see pattern for these three values - `6 = 6 +(8*0)` `14 = 6 + (8*1)`, `22 = 6 + (8*2)` so all of them give `(x-6) % 8 == 0`. And for numbers `10, 18, 26`  I see pattern `(x-10) % 8 == 0`

Comment: I added patterns `if x % 8 == 6:` and `if x % 8 == 10: ...` in first part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another general approach is to calculate the coordinates of all the corner points and then connect them with `goto()` calls. Note that all the relevant points lie on two concentric circles. I [recently answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68019499/13014172) a question about how to calculate regularly spaced points on a circle, so we could use that code here:

```py
from turtle import *
import math


# Settings 
speed(5)
width(1)
color('red', 'yellow') # outline, fill

r_inner = 50   # inner radius
r_outer = 150  # outer radius
n = int(input('Enter the number of points you want the star to have.')) 

# Calculate coordinates of the points on the inner and outer circle
points_x_inner = []
points_y_inner = []
points_x_outer = []
points_y_outer = []

for i in range(n):
    angle = 2 * math.pi * i / n
    points_x_inner.append(r_inner * math.cos(angle))
    points_y_inner.append(r_inner * math.sin(angle))
    angle2 = angle + math.pi / n
    points_x_outer.append(r_outer * math.cos(angle2))
    points_y_outer.append(r_outer * math.sin(angle2))

# Connect the points with lines
penup()
goto([points_x_outer[-1], points_y_outer[-1]])
pendown()
begin_fill()

for x_in, y_in, x_out, y_out in zip(points_x_inner, 
                                    points_y_inner,
                                    points_x_outer,
                                    points_y_outer):
    goto([x_in, y_in])
    goto([x_out, y_out])

end_fill()
hideturtle()
exitonclick()
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! Thank you so much for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not clear what you mean by star.  What I mean by star is a geometric figure whose lines crisscross; that starts from a point and returns to the starting point, and at no point does the pen drawing the figure lifts up from the paper.

You are correct about not being able to generate a 6-point star.

However, I am able to generate a 14-point star and a 22-point star.

[image: Fourteen Point Star]

[image: Twenty-Two pointed star]